# reading an unsigned integer from a binary file

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, integer, unsigned

I am trying to read an unsigned int from a binary file with this code

```
std::ifstream in(file, std::ios::in|std::ios_base::binary);
    in.seekg(0);
unsigned int nv;
    in.read((char*)&nv, sizeof(nv));
    std::cout << nv << std::endl;
```

the output expected is `2`
but I get `32612`
and it looks like an address , even though I didn't ask for one.
what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the file opened correctly? `32612` is probably just the uninitialised value of `nv`

Comment: That does not look like an address. How does the file look like?

Comment: @Quimby i am sure that it could potentially be an address. (0x00007F64 to be exact). But i agree that it is not likely.

Comment: I would expect that your file was not read at all and 32612 was just random garbage in memory.

Comment: yes you all are right, it wasn't open in the first place